# React bootstrap: How to enable tab navigation when using Tab component

Tags: reactjs, tabs, accessibility, react-bootstrap, tabnavigator

I'm using react-bootstrap version 2.4.0 and I'm using the Tab component. I want the website to be accessible by tab navigation but when I use the tab component the focus is set only on the active tab item and never gets to the other tabs.

```
        <Tabs
          className="mb-3"
          defaultActiveKey="A"
          mountOnEnter={true}
          unmountOnExit={true} >
          <Tab eventKey="A" title="A">
            <A/>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="B" title="B">
            <B/>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey="C" title="C">
            <C/>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
```

I noticed that when the page is rendered, all the other tabs (not the active one) have `tabindex="-1"` on the button of that tab, which makes them inaccessible to tab navigation.

This is what the DOM looks like after react-bootstrap generated its HTML. You can see that the first tab button (the active one) doesn't have the `tabindex="-1"` attribute on it. The other buttons have it so when I'm using tab navigation they never get the focus and I can never click on them.

```
<ul class="mb-3 nav-tabs nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button type="button" id="react-aria2325882265-4-tab-A" role="tab" data-rr-ui-event-key="A" aria-selected="true" class="nav-link active" aria-controls="react-aria2325882265-4-tabpane-A">A</button>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <button type="button" id="react-aria2325882265-4-tab-B" role="tab" data-rr-ui-event-key="B" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" class="nav-link">B</button>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button type="button" id="react-aria2325882265-4-tab-C" role="tab" data-rr-ui-event-key="C" aria-selected="false" class="nav-link" tabindex="-1">C</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I use the Bootstrap Tab component and make it accessible with tab navigation?

I saw that if I use the Nav component it doesn't have this problem because it doesn't put the `tabindex="-1"` on the `a tag` that is generated by react-bootstrap. However I can't use the Nav component because I don't have a link to go to, but a component to render, and this is exactly what the tab component is used for.

Comment: the standard way keyboard navigation works with tabs is that the Tab key only gets you to the currently active tab and the left/right arrow keys then move between the tabs. See for example [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tablist_role#keyboard_interactions) . Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes! it works thank you! One more problem- I'm using rtl alignment, but the when i'm clicking the left arrow key the tab to the right is selected. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, I don't know this library at all.

Comment: Did you set `<html dir="rtl">` as explained by the [RTL docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/rtl/)?

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't help.. Should I open a new question about it?

Comment: No I guess you would need to create a [feature request over at React-Bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues). It’s simply not supported currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected behaviour of [Tabs as per ARIA Practices Guideline (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabpanel/) is that the arrow keys on the keyboard change focus within this composite component.

Depending on the visual presentation of the tabs, the left and right arrow keys are used for a horizontal arrangement, up and down for vertical ones.

[React-Bootstrap’s Tab component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/) implements the arrow keys, but both up/down and left/right navigate the tabs.